# How to make web page accessible only from certain links

Tags: php, html, database, paypal

I am making a website where you have to pay (through PayPal) before you can access certain secure parts of the site. I have it set up so the "Sign up" button takes you straight to PayPal, then once you're done paying there you're led to the signup (root/signup/index.php) page where you input your name, email, password, etc and this information is stored in a database. Once someone's information is in the database, they can sign in to the secure part of the site.

My problem is that users can bypass paying at PayPal by going to www.mysite.com/signup/ and inputting their name/email/pw/etc, which will still be inputted into the database, granting them access to the site without paying.

Is there any way I can make www.mysite.com/signup/ a page accessible ONLY from PayPal? I have a PayPal button set up to take users to the signup page after they complete payment, and I want that to be the only way users can access that page.

Comment: Are the secure parts accessible, if I've paid in the past? Or is it strictly a pay once, visit once deal? If I want to come back tomorrow, I need to pay again?

Comment: @andrewsi You pay once then the secure parts are accessible every time you log in. You can go back and visit as many times as you want and never have to pay again. I have a login system working though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well typically when the user is being returned from PayPal, you have them directed to a specific page on your site where you can then evaluate the data that PayPal has posted to you.  You could simply verify that the user made a successful purchase and if so, set a session variable and direct the users to your signup page. Only if they have a valid session variable indicating they are a paid customer would you then present them with the signup form.

If the user arrive at your page without the proper validation, you sijmply redirect them somewhere else, or give them some error message.

Comment: This is scant on technical details, but it's the only answer that is actually helpful with regards to the OP's situation and question. Consider adding information about PayPal's return variables if you can.

Comment: @sudowned That would vary based on the PayPal integration method he is using.  I assumed since he didn't ask about that part, that that functionality is already working.

Answer (score 1):

It might be best if you passed a flag as a `$_SESSION` variable showing that the user has made the payment, and then block otherwise.

If you really still want to check the referrer, you should have your script check the `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` variable and go from there. I'm not entirely sure how secure this is though.

Answer (score 0):

If you know that paypal only uses a set of IP addr to contact your site, it will be fairly easy to configure the webserver to allow only access from these. How ever, the IP could be spoofed. If you would really need to be extra secure, you would have to use certificates.